# Cell value for number of rows selected in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a cell value as the last row in a selected range.

For example if the cell value is 20, I would select A2:D20 (first row and columns are known in advance).

I tried as suggested in one of the earlier questions, however, it does not work for me.

```vb
n.rows = Range("B5").Value
Range(Cells(C, 4), Cells(AN, n_rows)).Select
```

Comment: `Cells(4, "C"), Cells(n_rows, "AN")`. Row then column, and enclose the column letter in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Say **Z100** contains the Number *20*.

then the `Select` code might be:

```
Sub qwertyui()
    Range("A2:D" & Range("Z100").Value).Select
End Sub
```

[image]